# Does reinterpret_cast cause a strict aliasing violation?

Tags: c++, types

why does it even exist? In what situations does it not cause a strict aliasing violation, and in which ones does it do cause one?

I mean, if you cast between two incompatible types, and the result of that cast is the only pointer that points to the memory it uses in the whole program, is it safe to use it then under the presumption no other alias references that memory? Is it safe then to cast it back to its original type and also use it assuming the variable where it is stored is the only alias to that memory location on the program? Thats what Im asking.

By using I of course mean reading and writing.

Comment: you should read this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Comment: It's always allowed to cast from a pointer to any object to a pointer to `char`, and the opposite. This is very common when reading from or writing to binary files.

Comment: @PaulBaxter I did read that. It does indeed talk about type aliasing, but using some obscure language that I, as not an expert, cant understand.

Comment: Casting in itself is not a problem. It is subsequent reads and writes that can be.

Comment: @MatiasChara Unfortunately it's hard to know how much to copy and how much to simplify. Can you clarify exactly which parts of it you need more information on? That would make this a better and less broad question.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I mean, if you cast between two incompatible types, and the result of that cast is the only pointer to the memory it uses in the whole program, is it safe to use it then under the presumption no other alias references that memory? Is it safe then to cast it back to its original type and also use it assuming the variable where it is stored is the only alias to that memory location on the program? Thats what Im asking.

Comment: You can `reinterpret_cast` any pointer to a pointer to (possibly `unsigned`) `char` or `std::byte` and use it to read or write the object's underlying bytes.  It's usefulness is fairly limited beyond that.

Comment: Okay thank you that's much more specific.

Comment: There's a lot of stuff in C++ that can be used to shoot yourself in the foot, the head, or any other body part you accidentally aim at. And they're all still in the language because they are insanely useful in a few edge cases. `goto` (why the eff did auto-correct just recommend groot?), for example. You can go years without even seeing a `goto` in production code, and it's still there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does reinterpret_cast cause a strict aliasing violation?

Not by itself, no. But its misuse can lead to such violation.

It is not a good idea to use reinterpret cast unless you know that you need it (rare), know that there is no satisfactory alternative (rarer), and know that it won't lead to undefined behaviour.

> why does it even exist?

As the name implies, to allow reinterpretation of types. The use cases are rare in C++ and not for beginner, nor intermediate programmers.

Some cases where an advanced programmer might encounter it useful:

- Serialisation
- C interfaces that use reinterpretation as a form of polymorphism.

> In what situations does it not cause a strict aliasing violation, and in which ones does it do cause one?

The cast itself never causes any violations.

Strict aliasing violations can only occur when you have casted to a pointer (or reference) of another type, **and then** indirect through that pointer and access the object. So, if you don't reinterpret cast a pointer (or reference), or you don't access the pointed object, then you aren't aliasing the type of the object, and therefore cannot violate the strict aliasing rules.

So, what is interesting is whether accessing the object with another (aliased) type is well defined or not. Here is a list from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast):

- AliasedType and DynamicType are *similar*.
- AliasedType is the (possibly cv-qualified) signed or unsigned variant of DynamicType.
- AliasedType is std::byte (since C++17), char, or unsigned char: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes.

Missing from this list is:

- The pointed object of DynamicType is pointer-interconvertible with another object of AliasedType.

---

> if you cast between two incompatible types, (...), is it safe to use it

Depends on what you mean by "use". If you mean indirect through the reinterpreted pointer and access the object through the "incompatible" type, then no that is not safe in general.

> and the result of that cast is the only pointer that points to the memory it uses in the whole program

This is irrelevant. It is in most cases practically impossible for a compiler to prove that this is true.

> Is it safe then to cast it back to its original type and also use it assuming the variable where it is stored

Assuming the cast to the other type was well formed in the first place, then converting to back to the original type is always safe.

Answer (score 3):

First of, the use of `reinterpret_cast` by itself does not trigger undefined behavior, but using its fruits most likely will - so we will keep considering `reinterpret_cast` itself, rather than it's usage. Also one has to note that casting to and than back is defined, as long as both types are of the same size, but there are few cases where one would use `reinterpret_cast` for this - in most cases, people would use `void*` as intermediate and `static_cast` would do.

Strict aliasing rule was always a bit of a controversy. It makes some compiler optimizations possible, but it also inhibits a lot of entity-serialization techniques, which are proven quite valuable over time.

There are very legitimate cases when entity-serialization is used, and large amount of systems use `reinterpret_cast` to *reconstruct* the data. Granted, this technically invokes undefined behavior, but this is a trade-off people are often ready to make.

With introduction of `bit_cast` in C++20, I hope the controversial `reinterpret_cast` will see it's dusk.

Comment: Interesting comments, but I'm not sure this is an answer, strictly speaking.

Answer (score 1):

> why does it even exist?

1. Because essentially any processing hardware can do it.
2. Because you could do it in C, and C++ developed out of C.
3. Because it's useful in cases in which it's difficult, or probably impossible, to replace.
4. ... and if you wanted to replace it, it might be with pretty much the same thing, e.g. a union where you write one member and read another.